# URI Online Judge | 1759 Ho Ho Ho

Tags: c, uri

Hello this is my solution to to uri 1759

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    for (j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        printf("Ho ");

        while (j==i)
        {
            printf("\b");
            printf("!");
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what I got wrong ..can you please help me? the link of the problem    https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1759

Comment: `"can you please help me?"` - Not without a description of the problem you're facing and code to demonstrate the problem, no.

Comment: Printing a backspace is a wrong answer. Judge didn't say anything about faking it for a terminal, but will redirect your exact output and check it against the correct answer, which won't contain any `\b`. You have to print one character after each `Ho` and that character is either a `space` or a `!`. So you can set that character for the first loop and change it for the last loop. OR, you can output a space on all loops except the first loop, finishing with `!`. But as this a challenge, I won't be giving you any code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution may *look* correct, it isn't *identical* to the desired output, because of the trailing space that you erase by inserting a backspace. So, the solution is to re-craft your logic to avoid having to erase that trailing space.. One way of doing that, which I don't advise to really use, is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i,j;
    scanf("%d", &i);
    for (j=1;j<=i;j++,printf("Ho%s",(j>i)?"!":" "));
    return 0;
}
```